# Error while setting current camera in QuickTime Player through Apple Script

Tags: ios, applescript, ios-camera

I am trying to set the camera of quicktime player(QTP) to one of the listed devices for movie recording through apple script. I am able to list down the attached cameras that are appearing in the drop down list of cameras in QTP. Here is the sample code which does that:

```
tell application "QuickTime Player"
activate

set myMovie to new movie recording

repeat with i from 1 to (get video recording devices count)
        log (get video recording device i)
        set n to (name of video recording device i as text)
        if "FaceTime HD Camera" is not in n then
            set current camera of myMovie to video recording device i
            exit repeat
        end if
end repeat

end tell
```

But while setting the current camera before "exit repeat" in above snippet I'm getting the following error:

> scpt: execution error: Can’t set «class curv» of missing value to
>   «class » "iPad Name" of application "QuickTime Player". (-10006)

Can you let me know what I am missing or how to set the camera appropriately?